# Timing issue between async initialisation and results loading in application startup

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm, xamarin, async-await

Seeking some input on a behaviour I'm noticing in my code below.  This is my first attempt at async/await using Xamarin Forms and I have perused hundreds of posts, blogs and articles on the subject  including the writings from Stephen Cleary on async from constructors and best practices to avoid locking.  Although I am using a MVVM framework I assume my issue is more generic than that so I'll ignore it for the moment here.

If I am still missing something or there are ways to improve what I'm trying to do ... happy to listen and learn.

At a high level the logic is as follows:

- Application starts and initialises
- During initialisation verify database exist and if not - create the SQLite DB.  **Currently I force this every time** to simulate a new application and pre-populate it with some sample data for development purposes
- After initialisation completed load results set and display

This works most of the time but I have noticed 2 infrequent occurrences due to the async handling of the database initialisation and pre-populating:

- Occasionally not all sample records created are displayed once the app started up - I assume this is because the pre-population phase has not completed when the results are loaded
- Occasionally I get an error that one of the tables have not been created - I assume this is because the database initialisation has not completed when the results are loaded

The code - simplified to show the flow during initialisation and startup:

**----------- VIEW / PAGE MODEL ----------------**

```html
 public class MyListItemsPageModel  
{
 private ObservableRangeCollection<MyListItem> _myListItems;
 private Command loadItemsCommand;
 
 public MyListItemsPageModel() 
 {
  _myListItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<MyListItem>();
 }

   public override void Init(object initData)
   {
   if (LoadItemsCommand.CanExecute(null))
    LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
 }

  public Command LoadItemsCommand
 {
  get
  {
   return loadItemsCommand ?? (loadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsAsyncCommand(), () => { return !IsBusy; }));
  }
 }
 
 public ObservableRangeCollection<MyListItem> MyListItems {
  get { return _myListItems ?? (_myListItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<MyListItem>()); }  
  private set {
   _myListItems = value;
  }
 }
 
 private async Task ExecuteLoadItemsAsyncCommand() {
  if (IsBusy)
   return;

  IsBusy = true;
  loadItemsCommand.ChangeCanExecute();

  var _results = await MySpecificDBServiceClass.LoadAllItemsAsync;
  MyListItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<MyListItem>(_results.OrderBy(x => x.ItemName).ToList());

  IsBusy = false;
  loadItemsCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
 }
}
```

**----------- DB Service Class ----------------**

*// THERE IS A SPECIFIC SERVICE LAYER BETWEEN THIS CLASS AND THE PAGE VIEW MODEL HANDLING THE CASTING OF  TO THE SPECIFIC DATA TYPE

// public class MySpecificDBServiceClass  : MyGenericDBServiceClass*

```html
public class MyGenericDBServiceClass<T>: IDataAccessService<T> where T : class, IDataModel, new()
{
 public  SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<ISQLiteFactory>().CreateConnection();
    internal static readonly AsyncLock Mutex = new AsyncLock();
 
 public DataServiceBase()
 {
          // removed this from the constructor
  //if (_connection != null)
  //{
  // IsInitialized = DatabaseManager.CreateTableAsync(_connection);
  //}
 }
 
 public Task<bool> IsInitialized { get; private set; }
 
 public virtual async Task<List<T>> LoadAllItemsAsync()
 {
          // Temporary async/await initialisation code.  This will be moved to the start up as per Stephen's suggestion
         await DBInitialiser();

  var itemList = new List<T>();
  using (await Mutex.LockAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
  {
   itemList = await _connection.Table<T>().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
  }

  return itemList;
 }
}
```

**----------- DB Manager Class ----------------**

```html
public class DatabaseManager 
{
 static double CURRENT_DATABASE_VERSION = 0.0;
 static readonly AsyncLock Mutex = new AsyncLock();
 private static bool IsDBInitialised = false; 

 private DatabaseManager() { }
 
 public static async Task<bool> CreateTableAsync(SQLiteAsyncConnection CurrentConnection)
 {
  if (CurrentConnection == null || IsDBInitialised)
   return IsDBInitialised;

  await ProcessDBScripts(CurrentConnection);
  
  return IsDBInitialised;
 }

 private static async Task ProcessDBScripts(SQLiteAsyncConnection CurrentConnection)
  {
   using (await Mutex.LockAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
   {
    var _tasks = new List<Task>();

    if (CURRENT_DATABASE_VERSION <= 0.1)  // Dev DB - recreate everytime
    {
     _tasks.Add(CurrentConnection.DropTableAsync<Table1>());
     _tasks.Add(CurrentConnection.DropTableAsync<Table2>());
    

     await Task.WhenAll(_tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    _tasks.Clear();
    _tasks.Add(CurrentConnection.CreateTableAsync<Table1>());
    _tasks.Add(CurrentConnection.CreateTableAsync<Table2>());
    

    await Task.WhenAll(_tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

    _tasks.Clear();
    _tasks.Add(UpgradeDBIfRequired(CurrentConnection));

    await Task.WhenAll(_tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
   }

   IsDBInitialised = true;
  }
 private static async Task UpgradeDBIfRequired(SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection)
 {
  await CreateSampleData();
  return;

        // ... rest of code not relevant at the moment
 }

 private static async Task CreateSampleData()
 {
  IDataAccessService<MyListItem> _dataService = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IDataAccessService<MyListItem>>();
  ObservableRangeCollection<MyListItem> _items = new ObservableRangeCollection<MyListItem>(); ;

  _items.Add(new MyListItem() { ItemName = "Test 1", ItemCount = 14 });
  _items.Add(new MyListItem() { ItemName = "Test 2", ItemCount = 9 });
  _items.Add(new MyListItem() { ItemName = "Test 3", ItemCount = 5 });

  await _dataService.SaveAllItemsAsync(_items).ConfigureAwait(false);

  _items = null;
  _dataService = null;

  IDataAccessService<Sample> _dataService2 = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IDataAccessService<AnotherSampleTable>>();
  ObservableRangeCollection<Sample> _sampleList = new ObservableRangeCollection<Sample>(); ;

  _sampleList.Add(new GuestGroup() { SampleName = "ABC" });
  _sampleList.Add(new GuestGroup() { SampleName = "DEF" });
  

  await _dataService2.SaveAllItemsAsync(_sampleList).ConfigureAwait(false);

  _sampleList = null;
  _dataService2 = null;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `DataServiceBase` constructor, you're calling `DatabaseManager.CreateTableAsync()` but not awaiting it, so by the time your constructor exits, that method has not yet completed running, and given that it does very little before awaiting, it's probably barely started at that point. As you can't effectively use await in a constructor, you need to remodel things so you do that initialisation at some other point; e.g. perhaps lazily when needed.

Then you also want to *not* use `.Result`/`.Wait()` whenever possible, especially as you're in an async method anyway (e.g. `ProcessDBScripts()`), so instead of doing

```
var _test = CurrentConnection.DropTableAsync<MyListItem>().Result;
```

rather do

```
var _test = await CurrentConnection.DropTableAsync<MyListItem>();
```

You also don't need to use `Task.Run()` for methods that return `Task` types anyway.  So instead of

```
_tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => CurrentConnection.CreateTableAsync<MyListItem>().ConfigureAwait(false)));
_tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => CurrentConnection.CreateTableAsync<AnotherSampleTable>().ConfigureAwait(false)));
```

just do

```
_tasks.Add(CurrentConnection.CreateTableAsync<MyListItem>()));
_tasks.Add(CurrentConnection.CreateTableAsync<AnotherSampleTable>()));
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've implemented the recommendations and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

sellotape has correctly diagnosed the code problem: the constructor is starting an asynchronous method but nothing is (a)waiting for it to complete. A simple fix would be to add `await IsInitialized;` to the beginning of `LoadAllItemsAsync`.

However, there's also a design problem:

> After initialisation completed load results set and display

That's not possible on Xamarin, or any other modern UI platform. You *must* load your UI immediately and synchronously. What you should do is immediately display a splash/loading page and *start* the asynchronous initialization work. Then, when the async init is completed, *update* your VM/UI with your "real" page. If you just have `LoadAllItemsAsync` await `IsInitialized`, then your app will sit there for some time showing the user zero data before it "fills in".

You may find my [`NotifyTask<T>` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async) (available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.Mvvm.Async)) useful here if you want to show a splash/spinner instead of zero data.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  I implemented the recommendations and it works great.  As for the design issue - I did that on purpose to make sure I come to grips with the async / await design.  But I did move it from the constructor to the LoadAllItemsAsync function.  Now that I've got it working I'll move it to a startup / splash screen.  

Do you have any examples around for the NotifyTask<T> type?

Comment: I have some examples of a similar type in my [article on async data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx)